# Proving $A_{\epsilon}= \left\{n\in\mathbb N |\frac 1 {2^n+n}\ge\epsilon \right \} $ is finite.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Prove that $A_{\epsilon}= \left\{n\in\mathbb N |\frac 1 {2^n+n}\ge\epsilon \right \}  $ is a finite set.

Before that I had to prove that  $\forall \epsilon>0:\exists M:\forall n\ge M\Rightarrow\frac 1 {2^n+n}<\epsilon$ which is the same as saying that its limit is zero.

My idea about this is to assume by contra position that $|A_{\epsilon}|$ is an infinite set, but we know that for all $n,\epsilon: \frac 1 {2^n+n}<\epsilon$ so we get a contradiction and from the negation of the sequence limit definition we can tell that there exist $n,\epsilon$ such that $ \frac 1 {2^n+n}\ge \epsilon$ so it can't be infinite, nor an empty set. Is that okay?

Comment: Let me guess: is $\;0<\epsilon\in\Bbb R\;$ a constant...? The given data isn't clear, and **what's the question exactly** is even less clear. Please correct this.

Comment: @Timbuc yeah $\;0<\epsilon\in\Bbb R\;$

Comment: @Timbuc the question asks to show that the set $A_{\epsilon}$ is finite.

Comment: Yes, but there seems to be a looooong list of things you don't tell: apparently, you're given the *sequence* $\;\left\{\;\frac1{2^n+n}\;\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;$ , you know the limit of this sequence is zero, and thus you know that **for all** $\;\epsilon>0\;$ there exists $\;N_\epsilon\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. $\;n,m>N_\epsilon\implies \left|\frac1{2^n+n}\right|<\epsilon\;$ , and the absolute value can go as everything's positive here...and etc. You **must** be way clearer when posting a question to people that don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n+n}=0$

So, for every $\epsilon>0\,\,\, \exists N(\epsilon)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that

$|\frac{1}{2^n+n}-0|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge N(\epsilon)$

Note that this happens **for all but** $N(\epsilon)-1$ elements.

Comment: Yes that's a given here...

Comment: I didn't read the whole question. Note that this happens **for all but** $N(\epsilon)-1$ elements. Now do you see?

Comment: Yeah I see, so there's even no need for contra position here.

Comment: This is the only thing that came to my mind on seeing the title.  Maybe, this is the simplest way. :)